# Cannot resolve symbol in Inflater in findViewById

Tags: android

`public class MainHomePageFragment extends Fragment {

```
public MainHomePageFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_home_page, container, false);

}
```

}

`
Error inside the findViewById of inflater.
I have the related layout file for this but still not able to access it.
I am not able to figure out why that error is coming. Please help me out. I have tried al the possible ways to debug this but I can't figure out what's going wrong where, Thank you in advance

Comment: show code please.  Did you clean-rebuild ?

Comment: yea tried it and it still doesnt work

Comment: Rebuild the project will help.

Comment: I just tried but it doesnt seem to solve the issue